# htaccess to change url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, permissions

I have the following code in my .htacess but it didn't work right. Is it because mod-rewrite is no "on", if so, how can i check?

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\$ $1.php [nc]
```

I wanted to rename my address, example:

http://www.abc.com -> http://www.abc.com

http://abc.com -> http://www.abc.com

http://www.abc.com/123.html -> http://www.abc.com/123

http://www.abc.com/12-12-12.html -> http://www.abc.com/12-12-12

http://subdomain.abc.com/123.html -> http://subdomain.abc.com/123

Basically removing the extension and ensuring that its www is intact.

Edited:

It was rewrote into

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond % ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*).php $1
```

but still not working

Comment: If I understand correctly, you also need to edit the URLs in your PHP/HTML files. URL rewriting does not change the URLs for you.

Comment: Currently, the url is http://www.abc.com/123.php, upon doing this, am i right to say that if i were to access http://www.abc.com/123 or http://www.abc.com/123.php, it should work and auto-redirect to http://www.abc.com/123? On top of that, either way, my homepage immediately drop me a 500 internal error when i was there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Step 1.

Change all of your links to have the `.html` removed from links. Make sure you have `Multiviews` turned off:

```
Options -Multiviews
```

### Step 2.

You need rules to *redirect the browser* when there is a www missing from the hostname:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

### Step 3.

You need rules to *redirect the browser* when a URL is requested with `.html` or `.php` with the extensions removed:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD)\ /([^\ ]+)\.(php|html?)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ /%2 [L,R=301]
```

### Step 4.

You need rules to *internally rewrite* the URI if the request was actually for a php or html file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.htm -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1.htm [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1.html [L]
```

### .htaccess

So all in all, you should have these rules in your htaccess (ditch any rules you may already have trying to solve this issue):

```
# Make sure Multiviews is off
Options -Multiviews

# turn on rewrite engine
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect requests that are missing www and not a subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# Redirect if requests is for a .htm, .html, or .php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD)\ /([^\ ]+)\.(php|html?)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ /%2 [L,R=301]

# rewrite to the proper extension if such a file exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.htm -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1.htm [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1.html [L]
```

So altogether:

- if browser URL address bar says: **http://example.com/index.html** it will be redirected to *http://www.example.com/index*
- if browser URL address bar says: **http://www.example.com/index** it will be shown the content at *http://www.example.com/index.html* (or `index.php` if that exists). Address bar remains unchanged.
- if browser URL address bar says: **http://foo.example.com/images/image.png** you will see the image at `/images/image.png`. Address bar remains unchanged.
- if browser URL address bar says: **http://foo.example.com/path/foo/bar.php** it will be redirected to *http://foo.example.com/path/foo/bar*
- if browser URL address bar says: **http://foo.example.com/path/foo/bar** it will be shown the content at *http://foo.example.com/path/foo/bar.php*. Address bar remains unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

Remove *.html*:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*).html $1 [L,QSA]
```

Add *www.*:

```
RewriteCond % ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I have    Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*).html $1   and it gave me 500 internal server error

Comment: Its still returning internal 500...Look at my question above for the latest code i used.

Comment: I tried the code and there was no error for me. Are you using `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> ` and `</IfModule>` ??

Comment: I tried enclosing the code with the <IfModule mod_rewrite.c> and </IfModule> and without. I still gte 500 internal error. http://www.akashijap.com.sg/secret/

Answer (score 0):

On which hosting is located your website ? Are you sure mod-rewrite is enabled ? Did you contact your host to put it on, if not activated ?

Solution previously posted by androbin (https://stackoverflow.com/a/12553613/1713771) is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The `.htaccess` file that I use:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
</IfModule>
```

Which removes the `.html` file extension and forces `www`.

Comment: And changing the `.html` to `.php` will remove a `.php` file extension instead.